# mongo.so working fine with php apache ini but not with php cli

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I added the mongo.so extension in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and its loading perfectly in php info.

But not working with `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Because when i try to run composer for adding mongodb lib

it gives this error

```
mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0
the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

Do anyone know what is the problem ?

Comment: is there any way to find that ext loaded in php cli or not?

Answer (score 0):

`mongo.so` (ext-mongo) is for [legacy driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) while `ext-mongodb` is the [new driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)